# how to get response for GraphClient messages

Tags: c#, response

How do I get response for this code given below.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var message = await graphClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: When you pause the debugger and inspect 'message', what can you see?

Comment: @DevanshiBindal The question should be answered, if the problem is solved! Even if you found the solution yourself.

Comment: Answered it according to what I did for the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a breakpoint on the message and then inspect it for the response and the values you want.